# Keep failing this test relating to the robot's movement, have tried a load of different approaches

Tags: javascript, math

Question:

You are given an input string that controls the movement of a robot, "F" means take a step forward, "L" means turn 90 degrees to the left and "R" means turn 90 degrees to the right. E.g. "FLF" moves the robot one step forward, then turns it left by 90 degrees, then moves the robot one step forward. Write a function that returns the minimum number of commands that the robot needs to return to its starting point after following all the input commands. You should ignore any characters that are not capital F, L, or R. Hint: you may wish to track the robot's position using (X,Y) coordinates, assuming it starts at (0,0).

For example:

- "RF" returns 3 (robot must turn twice and move forward one step (eg. "RRF")
- "LFRFRFR" returns 1 (robot must step forward to return)
- "FxLxLxFx" returns 0 (robot is already back at its starting point)

The number of commands needed to return to the starting point

Tests:

- directions: "RF" : expected 3, returns 1
- directions: "LFRFRFR": expected 1, returns 1
- directions: "FxLxLxFx": expected 0, returns 0

Here is my code below, as mentioned I've tried various approaches but this passes the second and third test.

```js
function solution(directions) {
    let x = 0;
    let y = 0;
    let direction = 0;

    for (let command of directions) {
        if (command === 'F') {
            if (direction === 0) {
                y++;
            } else if (direction === 1) {
                x++;
            } else if (direction === 2) {
                y--;
            } else if (direction === 3) {
                x--;
            }
        } else if (command === 'L') {
            direction = (direction + 3) % 4;  // Turn 90 degrees to the left
        } else if (command === 'R') {
            direction = (direction + 1) % 4;  // Turn 90 degrees to the right
        }
    }

    // Calculate the minimum number of commands using the provided logic
    const minStep = Math.ceil(Math.max(Math.abs(x), Math.abs(y)) / 2);

    return minStep;
}
```

Comment: Your code sees one move that will return the robot to original after "RF". What move would thast be? Make your program give that as debugging output and check whether you find that plausible. I think your program wants the robot to take one step backward, but it can't. To put it differently, please explain why your calculation of `minstep` only takes the distance into account.

Comment: @Yunnosch I don't have the ability to debug as its in an online environment, any other tips you can offer?

Comment: Yes, explain your calculation of `minsteps` in English. If you can't, take a chess board and a little toy figure and play around until you get the concept of the assignment. Then turn your solutions you instincitively find with your hand into a description. Then turn that description into an algorithm. And that into a program.

Comment: If you have no way of running your programs find one. No matter how brilliant you are, you will never be able to learn without trying, erring and fixing. Many users will tell you that you also absolutely need the ability to use a debugger.

Comment: Here is a list of errors in your code (no guarantee that it is complete): a) x-distance and y-distance influence the result not the same way, because of the `/ 2` b) positions left of origin and right of origin have the same result, because of `abs()` c) you only use orientation to track x and y d) you only use the larger of x and y distance, because of `max()` . I admire your "program to tests not to spec" approach, it was in fashion for quite a while, but you cannot program by throwing math operations at the input until it passes all tests; because of possible more complex situations.

Comment: Let me know when you need more test inputs with expected results, I think I can provide you some tailored ones that will lead you the right path through the needed improvements in your code. For that however you will have to find a way of running your code and seeing its output; i.e. other than the online judge. I could then turn that into an answer post according to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions if you like.

Comment: @Yunnosch I've managed to find a way to get some logs out of the online environment, and a very hardcoded way to get it to pass that first test but im not that confident in the solution so an answer post would be very much appreciated.
Really appreciate all the tips and advice!

Comment: You are wise to avoid the test-case-oriented hardcoded approach. I might provide an answer. First step is however for you to get the idea of the context. So for you as a human (i.e. no programming) what is the solution for "LL" and for "R". Explain what the difference is which you see when looking at the robot on your chess board, even if that difference is not visible in the correct answer, which is 0 in both cases.

Comment: Next describe the difference of "LL" and "RR", when not only looking at the chessboard in the final setup of the robot, but also obsering during the moves to get there. Explain why this difference is even invisible when looking at the chessboard in final state.